# Word find/replace with wildcards

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, find-and-replace

Using Word 2010.

I'm using wildcards to find a string -- 4 digit year inside parentheses.
([(])([0-9]{4})([)])

I want to replace with a line break (or paragraph, CR, etc.) BEFORE the string + the original string; however using "^p^&" or "^l^&" puts the line break AFTER the string.

What am I doing wrong?

The first image shows the original reference list.
The second image shows what I want to accomplish.
No matter how I structure the "replace" string, the line break gets inserted after the year instead of before.

[1st ref example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7t3Dm.png)

[2nd ref example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0coN3.png)

Comment: can you show us a sample of the dataset and an example of the output you want, please?

Comment: `^p^&` works exactly as you describe how you want it to work for me. I am using Word 2010 - which version are you using?

Comment: @Drew I am new to Wildcard, but your expression "([(])([0-9]{4})([)])" seems a bit hard to understand. Are you sure you did not overcomplicate it?

Comment: The find part works perfectly.  It only finds 4 digit numbers enclosed in parentheses.   The issue is with the replacement string.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a ^p in a replacement wildcard string. Instead use ^13

The replacement string would look like ^13^&

The Find and Replace dialog should look like this:

[image]

Comment: I have tried ^13, ^013, ^p, ^l and all produce the same result -- a CR is inserted AFTER the date instead of before it.

Comment: I added to my response a screen clip of how the Find and Replace dialog should look. It works in my testing.

Comment: In you testing the break occurs before the year -- so that the year in parenthesis is the first item on the line?  My find/replace box looks identical.

Comment: I'm wondering if I have something obscure in my options that is making the break appear in the wrong spot.

Answer (score 0):

Ok friends, I'm not sure where it is yet, but it has to be something in formatting.

I copied a section of the reference list and pasted text only to a new document -- both find and replace work as intended.

Thanks for all the assistance.